# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

i am a begineer
i want to make a project that use `compileSdkVersion 17`
but when run project give me this error above 
and this my code for gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sadeem.vl2player"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the support libraries v26

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

**You have to use**

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

Comment: i need to use sdk 17

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik You can't do it, but why do you have to use api 17 to compile?

Comment: want to use sdk 17 to try some library on it  like videoview

Comment: As said above you can't do it. You should be able to use with all libraries the latest release. It is really uncommon to have a library which requires api 17 to compile (dont' confuse with minSdk)

Comment: what i should do to use it what changes in my projects?

Comment: Change the line described in the answer. For more info about compileSdk and minSdk check https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd